# What causes TinyScroll lag/latency in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, tinyscrollbar

There is a JQuery custom scrollbar on the page http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ and when viewed with either Opera or Mozilla the scroll works just nicely, but when viewed with Safari or Chrome, there is this annoying lag/latency (about 1 second) from dragging to reaction, that should be seemless. 
I'm using Windows 7 Pro x64.

Found something, that may be related:
[Very slow JavaScript performance using tinyscrollbar update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055353/very-slow-javascript-performance-using-tinyscrollbar-update)

Comment: Works fine on Mac OSx 10.7 / Chrome 25

Comment: Not very smooth, but no massive delays. Chrome 25 m / WinXP and Chrome 27 Canary / WinXP

Comment: Works Fine on Mac OSx 10.7 / Safari 5.1